# Copying files. missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, copy

I want to copy a file from Downloads to a folder using copyfile buy I keep getting this error.

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile("C:/Downloads/kaggle.json" "C:/Users/juan/.kaggle/")
```

```
TypeError: copyfile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst'
```

Why is copyfile not detecting the dst? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget a comma?

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile("C:/Downloads/kaggle.json", "C:/Users/juan/.kaggle/")
```

Comment: Actually I did :S. However now I have this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Downloads/kaggle.json'` However I do have this json file in downloads

Comment: Seems like you are on Windows, try using paths with backward slashes, like this: `copyfile("C:\\Downloads\\kaggle.json", ...)`